# Postgres get json count over

Tags: json, postgresql, window-functions

I have a column that contains a json object. My goal is to get the total number of the array even if I'm using limit.

```
CREATE TABLE json_values (
   elems json
);

INSERT INTO json_values VALUES ('{"field1" : [{"val" : 1}, {"val" : 2}, { "val" : 3}] ,"field2" : []}');


SELECT json_array_elements(elems->'field1'), count(*) OVER()
FROM json_values
LIMIT 1
```

This displays the first row, but it seems that the count over() is not taken in consideration, indeed I get only 1 instead of 3.

Is there another way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a proper lateral join to make this work:

```
SELECT e.*, count(*) OVER()
FROM json_values
  cross join lateral json_array_elements(elems->'field1') as e(val)
LIMIT 1;
```

This is one of the reasons why set returning functions should not be called in the `select` list.

Another option that is probably faster is to use `json_array_length()` which was introduced in Postgres 9.3

```
SELECT e.*, json_array_length(elems->'field1')
FROM json_values 
  cross join lateral json_array_elements(elems->'field1') as e (val)
LIMIT 1;
```

Depending on what exactly you want to do, limiting the possible array elements before doing the cross join might be more efficient:

```
select e.*, json_array_length(elems->'field1')
from json_values 
  cross join lateral (
    select * 
    from json_array_elements(elems->'field1')
    limit 1
  )  as e (val)
```

But if you only want to get the first element of the array for each document, the following would be much faster:

```
SELECT (elems->'field1') -> 0, json_array_length(elems->'field1')
FROM json_values;
```

Comment: great answer, but json_array_length is actually available on versions 9.3+

Answer (score 3):

There's a function in to return the length of a json array:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html

```
SELECT 
    json_array_elements(elems->'field1') field1
  , json_array_length(elems->'field1') field_1_length
FROM json_values
LIMIT 1
```

I don't see why a cross join or window function is required in this situation, although it is possible to get the same result using them.

Answer (score 1):

Place `json_array_elements()` in `FROM` clause:

```
select count(*) over()
from json_values, 
lateral json_array_elements(elems->'field1')
limit 1;

 count 
-------
     3
(1 row)
```